# One additional socket message each time user goes in an out of view

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, swift2

In one of my view controllers, this is how I have my socket listener defined:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        listenSocket()
}

func listenSocket(){
  socket.on("new_comment") { (data, ack) -> Void in
    ...
  }
}
```

What I noticed was that every time I exit and re-enter this view, I get one extra socket message from my server. Could this be because I am doing `socket.on` on `viewDidLoad`, so each time the user goes to this view, there is an extra "on" listener?

If that is the case, what can I do to not receive multiple messages?

Comment: `viewDidLoad()` is not necessarily called each time your view is displayed. If the view is already in memory then this method will not be called.

Comment: Then the question remains why I'm getting multiple socket messages.